# What is a good introductory textbook for neuroscience at the advanced undergraduate or early graduate level?

Tags: reference-request

I'm interested learning about the brain from a multifaceted perspective, i.e. I would like to learn about the basics of structure (anatomy) as well as function, and also a little bit of the computational perspective. In other words, I'm looking for a well-rounded introductory text at the advanced undergrad level.

Any references would be appreciated.